# Invalid JSON RPC response on ropsten

Tags: ropsten

I am trying to connect to https://ropsten.infura.io/my key here with web3.js. I can read stuff off the block chain but cant write to it and have no idea why. Any help?

Comment: Share the code for a write operation that is failing.

Comment: Infura doesn't support `sendTransaction` you have to create transaction on your side sign them with your private key and use `sendSignedTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

solved it. The problem was that I was trying to talk to my 'transaction' function directly. Which can not be done. Instead, sending a raw transaction did the magic.